# RequireJS script in an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have a website based on AngularJS.
To load js applications I use requirejs as follow:

```
<script data-main="/folder/to/myjsapp" src="/folder/to/require.js"></script>
```

Now I need to include the require.js script in an angular directive template.

```
<mycustomdirective></mycustomdirective>
```

But, after checking the network with chrome, it seems that the request for require.js and then myjsapp.js doesn't trigger. This only when I include the script in an AngularJS directive.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you loading it in a directive if you've already loaded it in a script tag?

Comment: Other small js custom applications are loaded outside the directive. This custom directive is part of a ng-switch container and should load its inner js application only when ng-switch-when meets the condition. After some researches I found that probably I should use some lazy loading techniques, or load requireJS externally and then manually trigger the requirejs function to load the directive script... but I still have to figure out how.

Comment: IF you are interested in lazy loading with RequireJS and Angular, take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/). You can lazy load code both automatically (based on routes) and manually.